# Using 'this' to make values in object

Tags: javascript, this

```
var obj = {
   name : 'object',
   itis : this.name,
}
```

why is itis undefined? When I look at the values of the object itis value is blank. Thank-you.

Comment: `this` refers to what?

Comment: `this` does not refer to `obj`, it refers to whatever `this` refers to in this scope.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is defined by the scope where it appears. So, you can't use `this` the way you want in an object literal, because the object literal doesn't have its own scope.

`this` has the meaning given to it by the current scope (i.e., the global scope or that of a function or method). You can do this:

```
var obj = {
   name : 'object',
   itis : 'object'
}
```

or this:

```
function Obj() {
    this.name = 'object';
    this.itis = this.name;
}
var obj = new Obj();
```

but what you're trying won't work. Here's an example of the problem in action:

```
function Foo() {
    this.name = "My function";

    var obj = {
       name : 'My literal object',
       itis : this.name
    }

    alert(obj.itis); // "My function"
}
Foo();
```

The alert shows `My function` because `this` is defined in the scope of `Foo`; `obj` doesn't have its own scope.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
var obj = { name: 'object';
            itis: this.name };
```

is perfectly equivalent to

```
var obj = {};
obj.name = 'object';
obj.itis = this.name;
```

in other words the `this` refer to the current `this` of the external scope and has nothing to do with the newly created object.

Things are different with

```
var obj = {};
obj.name = 'object';
obj.itisf = function(){ return this.name; }

console.log(obj.itisf()); // Shows "object"
```

and it happens because `this`, **when executing the function**, will become the object.

A simple rationalization is that when you call a function right after getting it from an object using `.` the `this` in that function will become the object. The rule implies also that in Javascript:

```
obj.f();
```

and

```
var ff = obj.f;
ff();
```

to **not** do the same thing, because in the first case only during the execution of the code in `f` the value of `this` will be the object. In the second case instead `this` will be the global object.

Answer (score 0):

`this` keyword does not refer to the object even though you use that inside one. It just refers to the thing that initiated the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the object `obj` when you pass `this` in a function:

```
var obj = {
   name : 'object',
  itis : function(){
    return this.name;
  }
}
obj.itis();//'object'
```

Answer (score 0):

'this' keyword refers to the current scope and in your case; you're using 'this' inside object literal declaration,and I guess, where 'this' would be referring to the 'Window' object.

if we see syntax wise, there would be no error. But at run time it will be 'Undefined'. Look at the below example

```js
var xyz = {
  
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: this.a + this.b
  
};
document.write(xyz.a," and ",xyz.b);
document.write(xyz.c);
// to cross check
document.write(Window.a + Window.b);
// Why NaN ?
document.write( undefined + undefined );
```